# CFBundleVersion must be a period-separated list

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, app-store-connect

I'm really having a problem with uploading my build to itunes connect. I always get the following error

[image]

My general project settings look like this

[image]

I'm also using cocoapods in my project but have never received this error before and I already have uploaded a couple of builds. I have no idea where that strange number `[1443188838-89]`comes from.

Also on the info tab the bundle version looks fine to me

[image]

As well as info.plist as source code looks good

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you look in the "Info" tab instead of "General", do you see anything strange for the "Bundle versions string, short" entry, or any other entries?

Comment: Click into the field, Cmd + a, delete. enter it again.

Comment: have updated my question with screenshots, still the same error

Comment: Ugh. OK going out on a limb, I think Xcode expects the build number to be an integer without periods, so maybe using "1.0.0" there is confusing the validation process?

Comment: @TomHarrington I've also tried it with just single version numbers like "1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so after spending a lot of time on this issue I finally could solve it.

Check **all** your Info.plist files if there is a wrong `CFBundleVersion` number in their. Go through all your Cocoapods **and** static frameworks and their bundles (right click - show package content) as well. In my case it was an incorrect `CFBundleVersion` key in the Netverify (Jumio) framework and bundle. (same as shown in the error message).

I have just changed it to a valid key like 1.0.0 and now it works!

Answer (score 3):

You are right, the problem is non numberic CocoaPods versions, but I don't suggest fixing it manually. This script in `Podfile` does the job:

```
# fix for non numeric CocoaPods versions
# https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4421#issuecomment-151804311
post_install do |installer|
  plist_buddy = "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy"
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    plist = "Pods/Target Support Files/#{target}/Info.plist"
    original_version = `#{plist_buddy} -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "#{plist}"`.strip
    changed_version = original_version[/(\d+\.){1,2}(\d+)?/]
    unless original_version == changed_version
      puts "Fix version of Pod #{target}: #{original_version} => #{changed_version}"
      `#{plist_buddy} -c "Set CFBundleShortVersionString #{changed_version}" "Pods/Target Support Files/#{target}/Info.plist"`
    end
  end
end
```

Example output for ReactiveCocoa 4:

```
Installing ReactiveCocoa (4.0.4-alpha-1)
(...)
Fix version of Pod ReactiveCocoa: 4.0.4-alpha-1 => 4.0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue as well, even with builds that were already uploaded and released to internal testing in TestFlight. It would not allow me to release to external testers for the same reason of the version string must be three numerals separated by periods.

I was using Cocoapods building frameworks with Swift and did a search through my project and found that RxSwift's Info.plist has the version string set to '2.0.0-alpha'. Thankfully I hadn't begun using it heavily so I was able to remove the pod and successfully submit without issue. You should be able to modify the offending pod's version string to get your submission to go through (though this is obviously not ideal).

I don't know if this is a bug in Apple's services or a new policy but either way it's painful.

Comment: I went through all info.plist files in the pods folder and it seems that nearly every pod uses `<key>CFBundleVersion</key><string>${CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION}</string>` to set the CFBundleVersion

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to update pod SVWebViewController in Podfile:

from

```
pod SVWebViewController, :HEAD

//Info.plist
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>HEAD 1.0</string>
```

to

```
pod SVWebViewController

//Info.plist
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
```

This update made a change in Info.plist file for this particular pod. Thanks for a hint user1463853.